# Using the User Trusted Credentials for a HTTPS connection

Tags: java, android, https, certificate, x509

I'm writing an Android app that needs to perform a HTTPS connection to some web server in my network.

This web server has a server certificate signed by a custom certificate authority so obviously, attempting a simple connection fails because the CA is not known at the time the device tries to establish the connection: fair enough.

Now I downloaded the CA certificate on the device and imported it in the User "Trusted credentials" setting page. It shows up (under the "User" tab) and I can click on it and see it has the expected details.

However, this new CA certificate seems to be ignored by the device when it performs HTTPS connection, and I got the exact same error I had before when connecting:

> Trust anchor for certification path not found.

The same thing happens if I try to browse to the server using Chrome on the device. I'm told that "there are problems with the security certificate for this site".

I tested my certification chain using `openssl verify` and everything seems fine.

I am at loss trying to understand what happens here.

I can live without being able to open the web server page in the browser, but I'd like at least to be able to establish a connection from my app using the User "Trusted credentials" list (and no, disabling certificate verification altogether is **not** an acceptable solution).

How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you not treat the same as a self signed cert?

Comment: @user2310289: Treat the same... what ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong:

I was using:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

Which for some reason, could not work with my test flask SSL-only enabled server.

Things were better when I changed it to:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

Still not sure why that happens, but it clearly solved it for me.